# Need to learn how to correctly access instance variables by "this" pointer, like it can simply be done in Java

Tags: java, c++

Hello I have experience in Java programming. I am not sure how to set the instance variables with the c++ programming language. I understand the "this" refers to the memory address of the current object instance, such as Java but behind the scenes.

I have both the .h and .cpp in place, how do I set instance variables in a constructor like done in Java.

I thought it may be as I have done below in the code. but I get an error explaining the variables are private, which they are of course. I am under the assumption a class has access to its own instance variables.

the variables of this class were inherited from a base class.

My main point of interest is understanding how i can correctly access instance variables and set them via constructor methods.Thanks.

```
LevelStructure::LevelStructure(double newX, double newY, int newWidth, int newHeight, string spriteSheetName)
{
    this->x = newX;
    this->y = newY;
    this->width = newWidth;
    this->height = newHeight;
}
```

Comment: In a constructor you would typically use the *constructor initialization list*, rather than assign values to default constructed members. In that case you wouldn't even need to use `this`. But your question isn't clear.

Comment: You say "the variables are private, which they are of course", and then you say "the variables of this class were inherited from a base class". Don't you need to make them `protected`, just like in Java?

Comment: Still worth reading: http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html

Comment: @izstasare You are right they should be protected thanks mate.

Comment: You also would not need to use `this` as there is no name conflict between in the constructor parameter names and the names of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are inherited (I'm assuming `public`ly) from a base `class` in which they are `private`, you can't access them in the derived `class LevelStructure`.  They need to be `public` or `protected` to access them in the derived `class`.  You can then set them in an initializer list, something like this:

```
LevelStructure::LevelStructure : x(newX), y(newY), width(newWidth), height(newHeight)
    {};
```

Comment: If these are private, somehow inherited variables, there is for sure an inherited constructor to initialize 'em.